# ionic run fails with exception > org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: node.js, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework, ant

I tried building a demo app following [Ionic's](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/intro/installation/) tutorials and I seem to be stuck.

`ionic serve` launches a browser with the new app quite nicely, but when i try on an android emulator or device, things get a bit confusing.

```
c:\ionic\mec>ionic run android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\ionic\mec\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js c:\ionic\mec


add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is
 currently set to D:\emmasony\data\andriod\android-ndk-r10c;.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.
properties to remove this warning.





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 20


* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.015 secs

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

build.gradle-line: 20 --> `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Same is the issue when `cordova run android` is used.

Runnung with Ant:

```
c:\ionic\mec>ionic run android -- --ant
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" c:\ionic\mec\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js c:\ionic\mec


add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Buildfile: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\build.xml

Buildfile: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\build.xml


-set-mode-check:


-set-debug-files:

-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.3

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mec774388


-check-env:


 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.3

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk


-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mec774388


  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-set-debug-mode:


-debug-obfuscation-check:


-pre-build:

-build-setup:

  [gettype] Project Type: Application



-pre-clean:


clean:

   [delete] Deleting directory c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin

   [delete] Deleting directory c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\gen

[getlibpath] Library dependencies:

[getlibpath]
[getlibpath] ------------------
[getlibpath] Ordered libraries:

[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 25.0.0


     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mec774388...



nodeps:


-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.3

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk


-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mec774388


  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library



-pre-clean:


clean:

   [delete] Deleting directory C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin

   [delete] Deleting directory C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\gen



BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds


[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 7.1.1

[gettarget] API level:        25

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin

    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res


    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\rsObj


    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\rsLibs


    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\gen

    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\classes


    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\dexedLibs

     [echo] ----------


     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mec774388...

[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:

[dependency]

[dependency] ------------------

     [echo] ----------


     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...


nodeps:


-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:


-check-env:

 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.3

 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

-setup:

     [echo] Project Name: mec774388

  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library


-set-debug-mode:


-debug-obfuscation-check:


-pre-build:


-build-setup:

[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 25.0.0

     [echo] Resolving Build Target for mec774388...


[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 7.1.1

[gettarget] API level:        25

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\res

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\rsObj


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\rsLibs


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\gen

    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes


    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\dexedLibs

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for mec774388...


[dependency] Library dependencies:

[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency]
[dependency] ------------------


-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...

[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.


-pre-compile:

-compile:


    [javac] Compiling 38 source files to C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes

    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

    [javac] 3 warnings

     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

      [jar] Building jar: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes.jar


-post-compile:


-obfuscate:

-dex:

     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...


-crunch:

   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\res

   [crunch] To destination dir: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\res
   [crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache


-package-resources:


     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...


-package:

     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-do-debug:

     [echo] Library project: do not create apk...


[propertyfile] Creating new property file: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\build.prop

[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\build.prop

[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\build.prop

[propertyfile] Updating property file: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\build.prop


-post-build:


debug:


-code-gen:

[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.

[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.

     [echo] Handling aidl files...

     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.

     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...


     [echo] ----------

     [echo] Handling Resources...

     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...

     [echo] ----------


     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...

[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.


-pre-compile:


-compile:

    [javac] Compiling 8 source files to c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\classes

    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

    [javac] Note: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 3 warnings


-post-compile:


-obfuscate:


-dex:

      [dex] input: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\classes

      [dex] input: C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes.jar


      [dex] Pre-Dexing C:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes.jar -> classes-a4da51b1799d4fae35ce5cc3e150107e.jar


      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\classes.dex...

       [dx] Merged dex #1 (33 defs/28.5KiB)

       [dx] Merged dex #2 (87 defs/110.0KiB)
       [dx] Result is 120 defs/164.8KiB. Took 0.3s


-crunch:

   [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res

   [crunch] To destination dir: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land
-hdpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: 97% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land
-ldpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png: 96% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land
-mdpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png: 97% size of source)

   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-lan
d-xhdpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png: 99% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port
-hdpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png: 97% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port
-ldpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png: 97% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port
-mdpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png: 99% size of source)

   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-por
t-xhdpi\screen.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png: 99% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-hdpi\icon.png: 67% size of source)

   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\mipmap-ldpi\icon.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-ldpi\icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-ldpi\icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png
   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-mdpi\icon.png: 0% size of source)
   [crunch] Processing image to cache: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\res\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png => c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png

   [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\res\mipmap-xhdpi\icon.png: 53% size of source)
   [crunch] Crunched 12 PNG files to update cache


-package-resources:

     [aapt] Creating full resource package...


-package:

[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run.

[apkbuilder] Creating mec774388-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...


-post-package:


-do-debug:

 [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...

     [echo] Debug Package: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\mec774388-debug.apk

[propertyfile] Creating new property file: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\build.prop

[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\build.prop

[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\build.prop

[propertyfile] Updating property file: c:\ionic\mec\platforms\android\bin\build.prop


-post-build:


debug:


BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 37 seconds

Built the following apk(s):
        c:/ionic/mec/platforms/android/bin/mec774388-debug.apk


ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Kwamena\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

No target specified, deploying to device 'FA35VW901817'.


Skipping build...

Built the following apk(s):
        c:/ionic/mec/platforms/android/bin/mec774388-debug.apk

Using apk: c:/ionic/mec/platforms/android/bin/mec774388-debug.apk

Package name: com.ionicframework.mec774388

LAUNCH SUCCESS
```

System Info

```
c:\ionic\mec>ionic info

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v5.0.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Also,

```
c:\ionic\mec>gradle -v

 ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
```

Running `cordova requirements`

```
c:\ionic\mec>cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-8,android-10,android-11,android-14,android-15,
android-16,android-17,android-18,android-19,android-20,android-21,android-22,and
roid-MNC,android-23,android-24,android-25,Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Prev
iew:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,Google Inc.:Google
APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23
Gradle: installed
```

I figure I'll soon use plugins that rely exclusively on Gradle. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some other issues led me to reinstall Windows, Android Studio and redownload the Android SDK. Everything went smoothly from there.